# Angular2 binding dynamic textboxes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let data of list">
    //here bind a textbox to the id and get its value so something like

   <input type="text" /> //am stuck
</li>
```

```
export class App {
 textboxvalues:any[] = [];

list= [{
   id: 1,
   value: 'One'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Two'
  }];
}
```

How can i bind both the value and id of textboxes such that when i collect the value of

```
console.log(textboxvalue)
```

it provides {id, value} eg

```
{1:"textbox1", 2:"textbox2"}
```

Or even as an object

```
{1, "textbox1"}, {2, "textbox2"}
```

Comment: [FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups) of [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms) may be the best option

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following:

```
    <li *ngFor="let data of list;">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.value"/> 
    </li>
```

The [(ngModel)] sets up two way binding so that as you change the value in the textbox the object in the array is updated as well. Don't forget to import the FormsModule though.

Here is a [example on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cfe28UL71VZg0Cu9tTw6). Everything you'll need is in app.ts. You'll see that as you change the textboxes in the first list the read-only list is updated as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
<li *ngFor="let data of list">
    <input type="text" name={{data.id}} [(ngModel)]="data.value"  />
</li>
```

This results in a form.value of:

```
{ "1": "One", "2": "Two" }
```

If you need to read from one property and write to another, you could instead try this (but I did not syntax check it). Note that it won't get the default values. It will only be set to changed values.

```
<li *ngFor="let data of list; let i = index">
    <input type="text" name={{data.id}} [ngModel]="data.value"
           (ngModelChange)="textboxvalues[i]=$event  />
</li>
```

Comment: How do i pass the values directly to textboxvalues, i can see your bind is to data.value

Comment: Put code in the submit button to take yourForm.value and write the values into the array.